# Sharing HTML5 app parameters through URL

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm looking into making an HTML5 app based on the WebAudio API. Within this app the user can set certain parameters. The user would then be able to 'share' this- that being when the share URL is sent and when another user clicks this they see the parameters set by user 1.

My main question is what is being able to do this actually called? I'm thinking it will have to be done setting the params through $_GET, which are stored in the share URL but I'm thinking there may be a less cumbersome way of doing this, which I don't know of, seeing as HTML5 has an offline mode.

Comment: `$_GET` does not apply to client side script. this is a PHP variable.

Comment: Either change the URL path, use a querystring or considering it is in JS even the URL fragment will do.

Answer (score 0):

Like another poster said, `$_GET` is for serverside PHP code, which doesn't sound like you'd need this. In an app, you could just modify the query string of the URL as the app settings are changed

```
http://host.com/?name=joe&email=joe@joe.com
```

And then you could copy/paste that link to someone, and they load the page, and on load, you can check the query string with [url](https://github.com/component/url) and [querystring](https://github.com/component/querystring) parsers to reload the parameters you want (like `name` and `email` in the example)